# Hexdump -C but decimal instead of hex

Tags: decimal, ascii, hexdump

centos 6.5 - running hexdump

```
$ hexdump -C filecsv
00000000  44 4f 53 2c 20 50 61 74  69 65 6e 74 2c 20 41 63  |DOS, Patient, Ac|
00000010  63 74 20 23 2c 20 4d 52  20 23 2c 20 54 69 6d 65  |ct #, MR #, Time|
```

Love this format but want hex to be converted to decimal
I have spent time looking but cannot find this?

Answer (score 7):

`hexdump` supports specifying a format string via the `-e` command-line option, and it seems to be pretty flexible.

Example:

```
$ hexdump -C b.c
00000000  23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65  20 3c 73 74 64 69 6f 2e  |#include <stdio.|
00000010  68 3e 0a 69 6e 74 20 6d  61 69 6e 28 29 7b 0a 20  |h>.int main(){. |
00000020  20 70 72 69 6e 74 66 28  22 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77  | printf("hello w|
00000030  6f 72 6c 64 5c 6e 22 29  3b 0a 20 20 72 65 74 75  |orld\n");.  retu|
00000040  72 6e 20 30 3b 0a 7d 0a                           |rn 0;.}.|
00000048
$ hexdump -e'"%07.8_ax  " 8/1 "%02x " "  " 8/1 "%02x " "  |"' -e'16/1  "%_p"  "|\n"' b.c
00000000  23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65  20 3c 73 74 64 69 6f 2e  |#include <stdio.|
00000010  68 3e 0a 69 6e 74 20 6d  61 69 6e 28 29 7b 0a 20  |h>.int main(){. |
00000020  20 70 72 69 6e 74 66 28  22 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77  | printf("hello w|
00000030  6f 72 6c 64 5c 6e 22 29  3b 0a 20 20 72 65 74 75  |orld\n");.  retu|
00000040  72 6e 20 30 3b 0a 7d 0a                           |rn 0;.}.|
$ hexdump -e'"%07.8_ad  " 8/1 "%03d " "  " 8/1 "%03d " "  |"' -e'16/1  "%_p"  "|\n"' b.c
00000000  035 105 110 099 108 117 100 101  032 060 115 116 100 105 111 046  |#include <stdio.|
00000016  104 062 010 105 110 116 032 109  097 105 110 040 041 123 010 032  |h>.int main(){. |
00000032  032 112 114 105 110 116 102 040  034 104 101 108 108 111 032 119  | printf("hello w|
00000048  111 114 108 100 092 110 034 041  059 010 032 032 114 101 116 117  |orld\n");.  retu|
00000064  114 110 032 048 059 010 125 010                                   |rn 0;.}.|
```

Not sure about how to reproduce that last line produced by `-C`.

See [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hexdump+1) for more details.

Comment: The last line will be produced by adding `-e '"%07.8_Ad\n"'`.